# subir una pagina php a github pages

Tags: php, github-pages

realize un sitio web muy simple con php, no tiene base de datos, solamente use php para poder incluir footer y navbar en diferentes paginas. El problema es que no se como subirlo a github pages, me tira el siguiente error :

The site configured at this address does not contain the requested file.

If this is your site, make sure that the filename case matches the URL.
For root URLs (like http://example.com/) you must provide an index.html file.

Asì es como tengo organizado el proyeco:

https://github.com/natalio540/autopartesramos.github.io

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Github Pages solo soporta front-end, no puedes correr lenguajes que se ejecuten del lado del servidor.

Comment: la extencion del index debe terminar en .html ó .md en lo que he visto

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo con la [documentación oficial de GitHub Pages](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/about-github-pages#about-github-pages):

> GitHub Pages es un servicio de alojamiento de sitios estáticos que toma archivos HTML, CSS y JavaScript directo de un repositorio en GitHub, opcionalmente corre los archivos a través de un proceso de construcción, y los publica como un sitio web.

Por ello no puede leer tus archivos php, y no los va a interpretar. Tendrían que ser archivos estáticos como HTML, CSS o JavaScript, y/o usando un [generador de archivos estáticos](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/about-github-pages#static-site-generators) como [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/).

> GitHub Pages no soporte lenguajes del lado server-side (del lado del servidor) como PHP, Ruby, o Python.

Answer (score 0):

Si es por incluir el footer y el navbar, solo debes crear los archivos html dentro de las carpetas include:

```
_includes/
  footer.html
  navbar.html
```

Cuando ya tengas listos tus diseños, los incluyes en las páginas específicas donde los necesitas, con el código:

```
<body>
{% include navbar.html %}
///contenido
{% include footer.html %}
</body>
```

En la documentación oficial de Jekyll sobre los includes hacen un ejemplo con un footer precisamente.

Comment: Perfecto. Gracias por el punto. Voy a editar la respuesta